# How to run jmeter requests with application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" (like postman's) setting

Tags: java, jmeter, httprequest

I am trying to set an http head manager element with application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"; param. I get the needed result from postman but there is a checkbox for this setting. I need to use JMeter for the rest api project.

Comment: What settings? Please post a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up HTTP Header Manager to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

[image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]

---

Actually you can just record Postman requests instead of building them manually.

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature), from JMeter's main menu choose `File - Templates - Recording - Create`
2. Kick off JMeter proxy. Expand `Workbench - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
3. Run Postman using JMeter as a proxy: `Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888`
4. Execute requests in Postman - JMeter will be recording them.

Comment: Thank you - I have configured it that way but still does not work as I want.
I do not want to use postman and to record its responses - i need JMeter so I can finish the suites in it.
Basically there is a a request from a external URL for 3D secured payment. 
As far as I investigated - postman's response param from this external URL is 3 times longer due to that encoding setting compared to JMeter's